# Concatenate two rows based on a condition using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, while-loop, pandas-groupby

I am trying to concatenate strings in two rows based on a condition. I used for loop to merge the values.

Input dataset and output column is given in the image

[image]

I used for loop to concatenate the values in rows

```
for i in range(len(Data)):
    j=i+1
    while j < len(Data):
       if(Data['key (Sum(col1to6))'][i]!=Data['key (Sum(col1to6))'][j]):
           break;
    if (Data['key (Sum(col1to6))'][i]==Data['key (Sum(col1to6))'][j]) and     Data['value'][i]<10:
         Data['ouput_code'][i]=Data['Col6'][i]+Data['Col6'][j]
else: 
   Data['ouput_code']=Data['Col6']
   j=j+1
   print ('last',i)
```

In my final output all rows are getting merged.

[image]

Comment: Please, can you edit your code indentation. Also, can you provide the data in text format. Nobody wants to type data from picture. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I want to let you know that I have not understood your question completely, but looking at the code I see following mistake which might be causing you the problem.

```
for i in range(len(Data)):
  j=i+1
  while j < len(Data):
    if(Data['key (Sum(col1to6))'][i]!=Data['key (Sum(col1to6))'][j]):
      break;
    if (Data['key (Sum(col1to6))'][i]==Data['key (Sum(col1to6))'][j]) and Data['value'][i]<10:
      Data['ouput_code'][i]=Data['Col6'][i]+Data['Col6'][j]
    else: 
      #Data['ouput_code']=Data['Col6'] # <== Here you are over writing the whole ouput_code column 
      Data['ouput_code'][i]=Data['Col6'][i] # <== I believe what you want to do is update just one entry 
    j=j+1
print ('last',i)
```

Is that what you wanted to do?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Right. I added two lines in code. Thank You...............
        Data['ouput_code'][i]=Data['Col6'][i]
        Data['ouput_code'][j]=Data['Col6'][j]..........        if (Data['key (Sum(col1to6))'][i]==Data['key (Sum(col1to6))'][j]) and (Data['value'][i]<10 or Data['value'][j]<10) :

Comment: Can this code be written using np.where which will reduce the processing time.